# Mysql data on remote server access on android device

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an app which has database in Mysql in remote server .I Want to access the data from my android device . My access of data does not require to modify the data it just should be able to check the database . 
1)Will I need the Web Services for this ?
2)If yes please help which web services , I really confused by looking at Soap,RESTful webservices.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not essentially a android question depends on the programming language you use at your server side

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously you must need to use web service to get the data from server. Better to use JSON data transfer format for that and we call it as Restful service as well. A very simple tutorial for that http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html